# Which service account is used for Storage Transfer Service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

When transfer service has configuration:

> Preserve Object's original ACL. This requires the **service account** to have permission for the source object

Which service account does this refer to? How do I find which service account is used for transferring the files?

---

The transfer service run failed with this error:

> Couldn't read source object ACLs. Source bucket must not have storage.uniformBucketLevelAccess enabled and the service account must have storage.objects.getIAMPolicy on the source object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to try the [`googleServiceAccounts.get`](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/googleServiceAccounts/get) method to get the Service Account used.

Just set the `projectID`.

Answer (score 3):

You may also use:

```
gcloud transfer authorize
```

to see the account name and missing permissions.